# Adding templated Date-Time dimension to the cube

Tags: excel, olap, cube

I have a database with FactSales table that contains Date column of type I4. I have created a cube and linked dimensions via foreign keys as usual, however, since I have no DateTime table in the database I create it through the wizard and it now shows in Dimensions folder.

Now the question is: how do I link the Dimension to the cube? I have attempted to do so in Dimension Usage but to no avail. Please point me in the right direction  to accomplish the task.

It now shows in Excel OLAP design, but does not filter by dates - most likely because it is not linked to the column in `FactSales`.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Update - it now shows in Excel OLAP design, but does not filter by dates - most likely because it is not linked to the column in FactSales. The question still stands - how do I link actual data warehouse table and dimension?

Comment: You can edit your question to remove obsolete information and add new details. Comments are primarily for clarification requests and may later be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution - it was as simple as changing my FactSales table' column Date to type Date, rather than having it as I4. After that I was able to bind it in Dimension Usage.